# Source with variable output impedance / Fast large signal voltage variable resistor

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-source, voltage-source

I need a source that has an adjustable output impedance.

Corner parameters are: Voltage range: +-5V, large signal BW > 10 MHz, output impedance range at least 1k to 500M. Larger would be better.

A big plus would be if the output impedance adjustment could to be fast, in the 10ns range.

I thought about a FET as a voltage variable resistor, but a) the signal amplitude is too large and b) the larger resistances are difficult to achieve.
Programmable resistors have values not large enough and don't have enough BW. The fastest ones I've found only go up to 5 MHz.

The best I've come up with so far is to use a series of switched resistors. The downside is the large stray capacitance, which severely limits the BW in the high resistance mode.
I would prefer a source with two analog inputs, one for the amplitude and one for the impedance. The smallest possible stray capacitance at the output is important to get a large BW.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you say the signal amplitude is too large for a FET?

Comment: Too large for the linear region. 5V would get me into the saturation region.

Comment: If you're trying to create a nanoamp-level current source, this is probably not the way to go about it. What is your application for such a thing?

Comment: I am measuring transfer curves of nano devices with a very big nonlinearity and hysteresis. As the curve depends strongly on the load line, I do measurements with different source impedances. I use a source meter in constant current or voltage mode with an additional series resistor in front of the device. That brought up the question whether there is a circuit that would have a variable output impedance. With such a circuit I could program any load line and do things such as applying a voltage for a certain time and then immediately do a constant current sweep (within RC limitations).

Comment: Some semiconductor parameter analyzers do something similar, they have the capability to do an I/V sweep and switch to constant V/I mode as soon as some predefined compliance limit is reached. I have no idea what circuit they use, they are pretty fast, < 100 ns. Still, they don't have the ability to neither do constant I or V, but have e.g. 100M output impedance.

Comment: I think it is an interesting question, though maybe it is too old and you will not respond to this. But, I'm curious: why does this application require variable source impedance? What is wrong with either a current or a voltage source in terms of the device behavior? If it is really what you need, perhaps you could use a voltage-controlled amplifier, such as VCA810.

Comment: I am measuring I-V curves on non-linear+hysteretic devices (similar to a memristor). Each measurement is a cut through the curve along the load line. Fig. 7 and 9 of this [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hector_Vazquez-Leal2/publication/264623473_Existence_of_Multiple_Operating_Points_in_Memristive_Circuits/links/0d1c84f53b67690355000000.pdf) show the intersections in 2D and 3D. This is what got me to think about a drive circuit with variable output impedance to capture the entire memristive surface without switching out any resistors. Besides that, it is an interesting EE problem.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it is my limited imagination that prevented me from thinking of such devices as an application for this. I agree it is an interesting problem, and so far it seems I am the only person to have upvoted your question. Have you made any progress since asking? Perhaps it is worth editing your question anyway to highlight the uncommon application and bump it back to the top of the list for a while.

Answer (score 1):

> The best I've come up with so far is to use a series of switched
>   resistors. The downside is the large stray capacitance, which severely
>   limits the BW in the high resistance mode.

This is the problem in a nutshell - if you can't achieve it with conventional resistors then semiconductors (or anything else that might spring to mind) just won't work either.

You need to re appraise your requirements or look at things in a different way.

Comment: Is that really the best one can do? I can build a very high impedance current source with active components, or a near perfect voltage source. Why not something in between? The resistors work ok, but it makes me wonder if there is a reason that you can't make an active source that would allow faster and smoother impedance changes. I never saw one, but that doesn't mean it is impossible.